# ¿Cómo se llaman personas que tienen interés en el español?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

En el mundo del estudio de las lenguas asiáticas, hay muchos términos para referirse a los estudiantes o a quienes tienen interés en estos temas.

Por ejemplo, en inglés los *Sinophiles* son personas que tienen interés en todas las cosa chinas. Los *otaku* son los fans del *anime* y son muy comunes en todo Internet.

¿Cómo se llaman personas que tienen interés en el español?

Answer (score 6):

Podemos decirles: "hispanófilos". (Referencia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanofilia)